# Remoção ou desfazer vandalismo?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Nessa questão: [bksakasnckjbsakjcbkasjbclsd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244466/64969)

AP vandalizou-a por algum motivo. Ela havia sido fechada antes. Qual o destino que devemos fazer? Remover ou devolver à sétima revisão, antes do vandalismo?

Comment: Reverter, deixar um comentário pro autor questionando o motivos disso. E se ele insistir, sinalizar pra moderaçao bloquear edição.

Comment: Eu já reverti e deixei um comentário pra ele, mas se ele continuar insistindo em vandalizar sem razão, a flag é totalmente valida

Comment: Isso parece uma resposta, e não um comentário, @Articuno ;)