# Reportar edição maldosa da pergunta

Tags: debate

Nos últimos tempos tenho visto muito disso. Usuários estão revoltados com os outros e estão realizando edição para destruir totalmente os tópicos. Eu queria saber como reportar isso, e como saber quem aceitou essa edição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais detalhes:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/286715/revisions

Observação que essa não é a primeira vez que acontece. Outros usuários com nível de acesso maiores estão realizando o mesmo fato, excluindo códigos importantes, e alterando mensagens de erro das perguntas e atrapalhando a resposta dos outros usuários.

Comment: Acho que você não está sabendo fazer uma leitura correta dessas revisões. Nenhum "usuario com nivel de acesso maior"  "destruiu" a pergunta. Se ler com atenção a justificativa, entenderá que foi uma reversão, pois a adição anterior a ela vandalizou o post e o "usuário com nivel maior"(no caso, eu), fez justamente o contrário do que está acusando. Eu reverti o vandalismo.

Comment: Só pra comentar: posso estar sendo otimista demais, mas creio que ou o autor queria apagar a pergunta ou o autor estava testando o sistema pois não o entende bem, então não diria que é necessariamente um vandalismo, tem muitos usuários (veja que ele só tem 1 ponto e é membro a 2 dias apenas) que começam no site e ficam intrigados com as ferramentas e não entendem bem que o conteudo é publico, acham que é um site de suporte técnico e por isso não notam o problema que podem causar com isto (claro que isto é apenas uma possibilidade, só o AP pode confirmar o motivo)

Comment: `Observação que esse não é a primeira vez que acontece, outros usuários com nível de acesso maiores estão realizando o mesmo fato, excluindo códigos importantes, e alterando mensagens de erro das perguntas e atrapalhando a resposta dos outros usuários.` - isso é uma acusação grave, e como tal, precisa ser provada. Seria interessante demonstrar com links essas ações maliciosas ou suas acusações se tornam infundadas e podem gerar picuinhas desnecessárias.

Comment: Foi, realmente fiz uma grande confusão. Só queria saber como chamar atenção para edições ruins sendo aceitas.

Comment: @Sveen se o autor editar, não tem aceitação, ele é o dono da postagem, se o próprio dono vandaliza, não há como outros validarem como ocorre quando outros usuários editam e vai pra fila. E mesmo indo pra fila, costuma ocorrer da comunidade rejeitar a edição ruim feita por algum outro usuário e o autor aceitar depois. Como dono do post, ele tem voto majoritário, claro que se você ver esse tipo de coisa, pode reportar para que a gente reverta e oriente o autor. A reversão da pergunta mesmo foi um usuário que avisou no [chat] e eu vi e acabei desfazendo o vandalismo.

Comment: Eu relatei um problema semelhante um tempo atrás: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6437/64969; marquei que a sua pergunta responde a minha para deixar devidamente linkado

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A pergunta que você menciona teve a vandalização feita [pelo próprio autor da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/286715/6). Como ele é o autor, ele pode editá-la independente da reputação que possui.

Para quaisquer outros casos:

- Se o editor possui reputação suficiente para editar a pergunta de forma direta, basta ver quem foi o editor.
- Se o editor não possui reputação suficiente para editar a pergunta diretamente, há um link para a votação de aprovação. Segue um exemplo de como a página se parece: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/160100

Se você acha que algo errado aconteceu, sinalize a pergunta ou resposta vandalizada para atenção dos moderadores.

Answer (score 8):

Vou formalizar como resposta, pois discordo mais do novo título:

> Reportar edição maldosa da pergunta

Do que do anterior.

Não posso afirmar nada, mas não dá para afirmar ao contrário também e acusar que a intenção foi má mesmo, note primeiro que o usuário que editou é o dono da pergunta e também é importante notar que:

- Ele está registrado apenas há 2 dias
- Tem apenas 1 ponto de reputação (até o momento)

Com isto é mais fácil presumir que o AP:

- Não entende que o conteúdo da pergunta é público
- O AP pensa que somos um site de suporte e que a pergunta só servirá para ele e não tem utilidade posterior

Pensando (supondo) que ambos casos sejam o caso do autor (ou apenas um) é mais provável que o autor não entenda como o site funciona e que ele por não entender nada poderia estar simplesmente:

- Testando a edição
- Tentando remover a pergunta pois já teve o seu problema resolvido (como eu disse, tem gente que pensa que o site é um local de suporte técnico gratuito)

Isso não torna o AP mal e nem comprova ou afirma que a intenção dele foi vandalizar ou agir com maldade. Eu mesmo, quando entrei para o wikipédia, editei alguns artigos com conhecimento próprio, o que é contra as normas da comunidade, já que lá para afirmar algo é necessário fontes. Minhas edições foram revertidas e eu fui penalizado algumas vezes (pois tornei a insistir na edição). Houve inclusive testes que fiz acidentais e aos olhos de outros tenho certeza que iria parecer vandalismo meu, mas na verdade eu era como um bebê andando por aí sem supervisão e quebrando as coisas.

Não dá para sair acusando o autor de estar cometendo vandalismo (agindo com maldade) só por causa de uma edição sem noção na própria postagem dele. Outra coisa que discordo, me perdoe em falar, mas é isto:

> Observação que essa não é a primeira vez que acontece. Outros usuários com nível de acesso maiores estão realizando o mesmo fato, excluindo códigos importantes, e alterando mensagens de erro das perguntas e atrapalhando a resposta dos outros usuários.

Eu frequento o site diariamente, sou membro a 4 anos e um mês, eu noto uma ou outra edição equivocada, uma ou outra barbeiragem (que não é necessariamente por maldade) e te digo:

- Tem sim edições equivocadas
- Todas as edições podem ser revertidas, somos uma comunidade e todos moderamos
- A maioria das edições que removem códigos é por parte do autor
- Se houver um caso de edição que você discorda, você deve abrir uma pergunta específica sobre cada caso (pois cada caso sempre vai ser um caso e deverá ser analisado imparcialmente de preferência)
- Muitas edições, como remover mensagens de saudações e agradecimentos, são incentivadas na comunidade, pois a pergunta e resposta tem que ter foco na dúvida e não nas pessoas. Qualquer coisa além disso é considerado ruído.

Então não adianta sair acusando as pessoas. É muito provável que seja um entendimento errado do uso da ferramenta e se você notar você pode orientar ou abrir uma questão no Meta para o caso específico e aguardar, **pode até ser um entendimento errado seu** e as outras edições que citou podem estar totalmente aceitável dentro do que a comunidade acredita ser o mais próximo do ideal.

Comment: "Vandalismo é a ação de destruir ou danificar uma propriedade alheia de forma intencional, seja esta pública ou privada, geralmente sem motivo aparente ou com o propósito de causar ruína." ([Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandalismo?wprov=sfti1)). Talvez o autor não tenha feito por maldade, talvez apenas por desconhecer como funciona a plataforma. Mas devo concordar com as palavras do Sveen sobre "vandalismo", possivelmente não sobre maldade (não dá para julgar sem enxergar do coração da pessoa). Enfim, eu sei que sou ríspido e que não meço palavras, mas está dentro da definição Wiki

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mas vc falou o mesmo que eu, se não notou (ou se eu não consegui me fazer compreensivo), foi o que eu insinuei ou tentei insinuar, é que não dá para acusar que foi por maldade, nem dá para acusar que não foi. O problema é que que tentei ser construtivo e indicar para a pessoa pensar em outras possibilidades, como eu comecei na resposta: *Não posso afirmar nada, mas não dá para afirmar ao contrário também e acusar que a intenção foi má mesmo*

Comment: "Não dá para sair acusando o autor de estar cometendo vandalismo (agindo com maldade) só por causa de uma edição sem noção na propria postagem dele". Talvez o meu entendimento se bagunçou com essa frase. Às vezes o cara só seguia a Princesa Wanda filha de Krakus ;-) não é vândalo por maldade

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado você foi bem 'trágico' agora (sobre a princesa), falando sobre a resposta, talvez uma edição melhore o texto, palavras mais adequadas que vandalismo talvez ajude, ou só remover já deve evitar.